# Hive CLI shows DB usage even when DB is deleted

Tags: hadoop, hive

1) Create a DB and use it.

```
hive> create database testdb;
hive> use testdb;
```

2) Set hive.cli.print.current.db=true to show which DB is being used.

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
hive (testdb)>
```

3) Drop the DB.

```
hive (testdb)> drop database testdb;
```

4) Set hive.cli.print.current.db=false and then set it back to true.

```
hive (testdb)> set hive.cli.print.current.db=false;
hive> set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
```

5) Hive CLI still indicates that the deleted DB is being used.

```
hive (testdb)>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on DEV environment,

- You may want to enable **TRASH** feature. This can be done by setting
  fs.trash.interval=1 in core-site.xml. In few instances files/db arent
  moved to these trash folder.
- Check if appropriate rights are assigned to trash folder in the HDFS.
- Logout from the session and check if it is still persisting.

Comment: 'fs.trash.interval' is set to 360 in hdfs core-site.xml. Also, there is no hive directory in /users.